# How is the entropy calculated by the `entropy` package in R?

Tags: r, entropy

So, as per the docs, I'm calling the function like this

```
v = c(0,4,3,6,7,3,2,3,4,5)
entropy(discretize(v, numBins = 8, r = c(0,7)))
```

and I get

```
[1] 1.834372
```

jolly good. Now, the question is: assuming that the following is the algorithm used to calculate the entropy – taken from Wikipedia

$$ \mathrm{H}(X) = -\sum_{i} {\mathrm{P}(x_i) \log_b \mathrm{P}(x_i)} $$

my questions are the following.

1. What is $\mathrm{P}$ taken to be? That is, is it the actual distribution of $v$ that is computed with `discretize`
2. What is $b$? The docs state the the default unit is nat, so can I deduce that $b=e$?

Comment: Why not try out your suppositions and check?  Here's one way: `p <- table(v);
p <- p/sum(p);
sum(-p*log(p))`.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it did not occur to me that I could check that easily. I guess that's what they call being burnt out :)

Comment: @Morpheu5 ...and? Did you solve the problem? (So you could answer your own question here.)

Comment: Sorry, yeah, it suggests that that is the case, but I would rather find some external source that I can cite. It's for my dissertation…

Comment: @Morpheu5 Then rather look at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/entropy/entropy.pdf or the actual code of this package.